# alter table laravel 4 with migration

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-4

I'm making a application with laravel 4; making a review of my application the database changed, and I need to make this changes. Instead of make changes in the databases directly I want to know if there is a way to alter the fields in the database through migration.
At first time I made this to add a new field in the table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('convenios', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('anio');                
    });
}
```

But now, I have to alter some fields, for example change String to Text. My database is PostgreSQL. How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rename a column:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

Or drop it:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->dropColumn('votes');
});
```

Other than that I'm afraid Laravel will still not support, so you'll have to go raw:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('alter table users alter column...'));
```

Check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/schema#renaming-columns

Comment: Thanks @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro